# JQuery scroll li id to top of div

Tags: jquery, html

I am using JQuery to scroll a selected list item into view within a div where the overflow is set to scroll. The following code works OK but it scrolls the selected list item to the top of the screen not the top of  `#QuestionScroller` div. This puts it out of view under the content above. I added `75px` offset but this is not ideal as the height of the content above can change depending on viewport size. So how to adapt the script to scroll to top of `#QuestionScroller` div not top of page?

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var contactTopPosition = $("#ListItemQuestion<%=Session["QuestionID"] %>").position().top - 75;
    $("#QuestionScroller").animate({ scrollTop: contactTopPosition },2500);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the code below. Hope this will be helpful for you.

```js
var container = $('#QuestionScroller'),
    scrollTo = $('#ListItemQuestion');
    container.animate({scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + 
                       container.scrollTop()});
```

```css
#QuestionScroller {
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="QuestionScroller">
    <ul>
        <li id='row_1'>111111</li>
        <li id='row_2'>222222</li>
        <li id='row_3'>333333</li>
        <li id='ListItemQuestion'>444444</li>
        <li id='row_5'>555555</li>
        <li id='row_6'>666666</li>
        <li id='row_7'>777777</li>
        <li id='row_8'>888888</li>
        <li id='row_9'>999999</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
`$("body").animate({scrollTop:$(“##QuestionScroller”).offset().top},2500)`
can it work?

Comment: I think that will scroll div #QuestionScroller to the top but I need to scroll list item ID #ListItemQuestion to the top of the div #QuestionScroller. Code in my OP above works nicely to scroll list item to top of page -75, but I need to scroll to top of div #QuestionScroller.